# wProps updating in react dev tools but conditional jsx not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble understanding why my child component is not updating it's conditional JSX from the renderFace method despite the prop values being updated in react dev tools and the value of the element being targeted also updating ("data-icon" value in photos 3&4).

[initial null value of fetched props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUaTp.jpg)

[populated prop values after fetched data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN28F.jpg)

[initial prop value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m1tA.jpg)

[updated prop value after state is fetched / updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLxkJ.jpg)

As you can see from the photos the data is updating in the dev tools but the frown doesn't turn upside down despite props value updating.

SearchBar is the child component of App

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      businesses: []
    };
  }

searchYelp(term, location, sortBy) {
    Yelp.search(term, location, sortBy).then(businesses => {
      this.setState({businesses: businesses});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <SearchBar 
          businesses={this.state.businesses} 
          searchYelp={this.searchYelp.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  this.renderFace = this.renderFace.bind(this);
 }

 renderFace(){
    return (
    this.props.businesses == 0
      ? <h1>Hangry <span className="iconify" data-icon="clarity:sad-face-solid" data-inline="false"></span></h1>
      : <h1>Hangry <span className="iconify" data-icon="bx:bxs-happy-alt" data-inline="false"></span></h1>
    )
  }

handleSearch(event) {
    this.props.searchYelp(this.state.term, this.state.location, this.state.sortBy);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

 componentDidUpdate(){
    this.renderFace();
  }

 return (
      <div className="SearchBar">
        {this.renderFace()} 
      </div>
 )

}
```

Comment: I updated the post @3limin4t0r its in the App component

Comment: I don't see a call to searchYelp--is that what you mean to have inside componentDidUpdate?

Comment: @RossHunter I omitted it because it searches and filters as intended; edited to include it

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova tried importing icons also, same result might try a different library

Comment: FYI, you don't need to call componentDidUpdate to make your render logic work.  Components re-render automatically whenever their props change.  Note also that the conditional `[] == 0` in your example works the way you want it to, but maybe not for the reason you'd expect.  It's more 'conventional' to check an array's `length` property to distinguish between a populated and an empty array, just to make the code easier to reason about.  Sorry if you know all that already, do as you like!

Comment: @RossHunter thanks for that explanation on operator difference, I was wondering why the results changed as I changed the operator between strict and reg. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged the problem down to determining if it was a logic issue or a library / src issue. I typed in some text which changed when the props were updated, inferring the issue was coming from the API. Installed the independent dependencies for the icons and it worked.

```
npm install --save-dev @iconify/react @iconify-icons/heroicons-outline
import { Icon, InlineIcon } from '@iconify/react';
import emojiHappy from '@iconify-icons/heroicons-outline/emoji-happy';
```